# Microsoft defender for cloud gives Findings have not been received yet for the VM message

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, qualys, azure-defender

I have created a Windows VM in azure and have added the WindowsAgent.AzureSecurityCenter extension and Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/providers/serverVulnerabilityAssessments through ARM template while creating the VM. Now under the Machines should have vulnerability findings resolved recommendation, the VM is getting listed under not applicable resource with a message saying Findings have not been received yet for the VM. I kept the machine running for 2 days and it is still not displaying the findings. Can someone help on this?

Answer (score 1):

If the VM is showing as 'Not applicable', it's possible it's not supported. You can see possible reasons for this here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/defender-for-cloud/deploy-vulnerability-assessment-vm#why-does-my-machine-show-as-not-applicable-in-the-recommendation